# Как перехватывать входящие смс только с определённых номеров?

Tags: java, android

Есть приложение, которое должно перехватывать смс и проверять, если смс пришло с одного из сервисных номеров, то тогда обрабатывать это смс нашим приложением (смс не должно попадать в список входящих сообщений на устройстве и не должно всплывать уведомление о новом смс; наше приложение должно извлечь данные из смс и обработать их - с этим проблем нету), если не от сервисного номера - то отправлять на обработку стандартному приложению для смс на устройстве (Messsages, Hangouts и т.д.).

Для реализации этой задачи нужно, чтобы наше приложение первым перехватывало входящее смс, а для этого судя по всему оно должно стоять как приложение по умолчанию для смс (если ошибаюсь - поправьте).

Но, если наше приложение будет стоять по умолчанию для смс, то допустим если наш `Receiver` перехватил входящее сообщение, но определил, что оно пришло не от сервисного номера, то это сообщение будет обработано в стандартном приложении для работы с смс (Messsages, Hangouts и т.д.) со стандартным поведением (всплывающее уведомления о новом смс и т.д.)?

**Итог:** нужно, чтобы наше приложение умело перехватывать и обрабатывать входящие сообщения только с определённых номеров телефонов, а со всех остальных номеров, чтобы смс обрабатывались приложениями, которые предназначены именно для этих задач (Messsages, Hangouts и т.д.).

Данный функционал должен работать с версии android 2.3 заканчивая последней.

Comment: Судя по описанию - это ровно тот функционал, который нужен троянам для воровства денег с банковских счетов незаметно для пользователя. Поэтому если в старых версиях андроида что-то подобное, возможно, и было можно сделать, то в новых версиях такие возможности должны быть надежно перекрыты.

Comment: @Yaant нет, в данном случае это смс с сервисных номеров для приложения, для верификации номера пользователя, различного рода подтверждений действий в приложении, отправки статусов/уведомлений, к примеру если у пользователя в данный момент отсутствует интернет и т.д. просто даже как минимум в силу того, что смс будут приходить часто - вариант с тем, чтобы у пользователя собирался мусор во входящих смс или пользователь каждый раз открывал смс и вводил вручную коды подтверждения - не самый лучший выход. просто если так судить, то можно практически любой функционал из пользы превратить во вред ))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Для реализации этой задачи нужно, чтобы наше приложение первым перехватывало входящее смс, а для этого судя по всему оно должно стоять как приложение по умолчанию для смс (если ошибаюсь - поправьте).

Ошибаетесь, только дефолтное приложение имеет доступ к БД смс на запись, а перехватить может любое - это не проблема.

Посмотрите на [исходники кастомного ресивера](https://github.com/ivanovpv/darksms/blob/master/psm/src/main/java/ru/ivanovpv/gorets/psm/SmsReceiver.java)

В ресивере надо распознать номер и если номер ваш - то просто вызвать `abortBroadcast()`, а если номер не ваш то пропустить его дальше по цепочке ресиверов, так что он доберется до стокового обработчика, который запишет его в БД и все такое.

Манифест примерно такой:

```
<!-- SMS receiver -->
    <receiver
        android:name=".SmsReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647" > <!-- 999 is highest system priority, so it's hack 2147483647 -->
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" /> <!-- pre kitkat action -->
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_DELIVER" /> <!-- kitkat action -->
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: `abortBroadcast()` - не работает для смс начиная с версии 4.4 Kitkat (API 19). Т.е. начиная с версии 4.4 и выше никак не оборвать цепь перехвата смс слушателями других приложений?

Comment: А ведь получается, что начиная с Kitkat открыли уязвимость. Ведь с таким успехом может стоять какой-то троян у которого будут разрешения на прослушку входящих смс и соответственно доступ к конфиденциальным данным из смс, которые должны попасть только в нужное приложение и больше ни в какое другое. И если в случае, с версиями < 4.4 там приложение по умолчанию с наивысшим приоритетом могло хотя бы оборвать цепь слушателей. То в версиях >=4.4 я так понимаю с перехватом смс приложениями, которым не нужно знать, что содержится в смс - разобраться уже не выйдет?